# Flutter GetX Hint Text Localization Problem

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-getx

I follow GetX localization management

`Text( 'greeting'.tr, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4, ),`

But once I try to use in hintText it is not working.

Is there any way to use getX in hint text?

Comment: Add Translation code and the error if happened..